# .NET installing umbraco in existing project dependecy with Owin problem

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am in the process of trying to install Umbraco in an existing project, and I'm currently getting the following dependency error..

```
Install-Package : Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' that is compatible with 'UmbracoCms.Core 7.13.2 constraint: Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (>= 3.1.0 
&& < 4.0.0)
```

I'm wondering what the best way is to get around this? I've attempted to down grade Owin, to a version less that 4.0.0 however, other errors exist within my project upon doing this. Anyone any experience with this?

Comment: Did you try to install Umbraco in a new clean project? Then you can try to compare and perhaps move stuff from the new, to your existing project.

Comment: which version are you upgrading from?

Comment: @MarioLopez - Im not upgrading. This is another .NET project I was trying to integrate Umbraco into.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'existing project' but I'd install Umbraco in an empty site and then copy any code you need into it.